# Does swagger UI support "patternproperties"?

Tags: json, user-interface, design-patterns, swagger

I'm writing a swagger contract, and have to use `patterProperties`, but when veiwing this on swagger UI, it fails. All parent parts appears, and starting the pattern item it disappears.

Here is what I'm trying to process

```
"nodes": {
        "description": "list of nodes",
        "required": "true",
        "type": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
                  "^[\\S]+$": {
                    "description": "node metada",
                    "required": "true",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "length": {
                        "description": "node length",
                        "required": "true",
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "width": {
                        "description": "node width",
                        "required": "true",
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
         }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger Yaml schema definition for object without a fixed property list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088771/swagger-yaml-schema-definition-for-object-without-a-fixed-property-list)